# What is load balancing in GCP?

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I use VMs in Compute Engine in Google Cloud Platform. When i create instance, google says me, that it will cost me one price(near 5$), but in reality it charges me more.

In detailed billings, I found out, that instances cost for about 2$ per 2 weeks, and 5$ more for load balancing.

I know what load balancing is(only in general), but where is it user, if I use only 1 VM per time? Do I really need it? How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, [GCE load balancers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) are useful to distribute the load between a set of instances. There are some other advantages they can provide like [autoscaling](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/).

If you are working with only one VM, you can certainly have the VM connected to the internet by the use of an [external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/).  The only thing to have in mind is that external IPs can change if they are defined as ephemeral. To  avoid this scenario that would imply to re-configure your applications to the new IP, you can define it as an [Static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address).

Answer (score 0):

^be keen on static IP though. do not reserve unless you will be using it. I read somewhere that reserved but unused static IP address will be charged like a cent or a fraction of a cent per hour